# How to update minted NFTs maxSupply to avoid 'none"?

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

A couple of months ago, I used [Metaplex Storefront](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/deprecated-storefront) to mint NFTs.

Back in the day, Storefront didn't allow creators to specify the parameter **maxSupply**.

> Max Supply: (Optional) The maximum number of times NFTs can be printed from this Master Edition. When set to None, the program will enable unlimited prints. You can disable NFT printing by setting the Max Supply to 0.

Source: [Metaplex Docs](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/accounts#master-edition)

So today, the Master Edition account doesn't include this parameter.

Some marketplaces refuse to list these NFTs as a unique Master Edition as the max supply field is not defined (set to 'none' by default). Is there a way for me to fix that for my previously minted NFTS?

```
"edition": {
    "type": "MasterEdition",
    "supply": "0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to update **maxSupply** after the NFT is minted.

Because max supply is undefined, the NFT is considered an open edition.

[More information here.](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/accounts#master-edition)